# Return List element pairs based on given criteria

Tags: java, linked-list

I've got a class `Category` with properties and constructors like so:

```
Double categoryRange;
String categoryName;
Double categoryPercent;

Category(categoryRange, categoryName, categoryPercent)

getters(), setters()...
```

I've also got a linkedList of Category objects like so:

```
[C1,C2,C3,C4]

where

C1 = new Category(10,"Music",20);
C2 = new Category(20,"Short Films",40)
C3 = new Category(30,"Films",75)
C4 = new Category(40,"MNM",3)
```

Now let's assume the `inputRange` is `15`. I'm trying to **return those 2 sequential `Category` objects between whose `categoryRange` the `inputRange` falls**. In this case, `15` comes between `categoryRange` `10` and `20`. So `C1` & `C2` will be returned.

Similarly if `inputRange` = `39`, `C3` & `C4` needs to be returned.

Now this can be done by iterating over every pair of `Category` objects in the list(i.e., `(C1,C2),(C2,C3),(),..`) and check if the `inputRange` falls between the `categoryRange` of the pairs.

But I was wondering, if there's a better way to do it.

If so, do let me know as to how it is possible.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a NavigableSet, which keeps the entires ordered and you can directly access the elements above and below any value.

Assuming you have a getter for `categoryRange`:

```
// Declare the set and how to order its elements
NavigableSet<Category> set = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Category::getCategoryRange));

Category C1 = new Category(10D, "Music", 20D);
Category C2 = new Category(20D, "Short Films", 40D);
Category C3 = new Category(30D, "Films", 75D);
Category C4 = new Category(40D, "MNM", 3D);

set.add(C1);
set.add(C2);
set.add(C3);
set.add(C4);

// Create a category object with the targe range value
Category search = new Category(15D, null, null);

// Voila!
Category below = set.floor(search);
Category above = set.ceiling(search);
```

There is a fancier approach, assuming `categoryRange` is unique, that could use a `NavigableMap` (`TreeMap` as the impl) with `categoryRange` as the key. Code is similar, and you wouldn't have to create the search object.

Comment: ,Thanks for the help. I would like to clarify one point. I'm fairly new to NavigableSet. Say the `categoryRange` is 20. Would the NavigableSet be able to return the matching `Category` object? In this case `C2`?

Comment: @Aron behaviour is clearly described in the [javadoc for `floor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#floor-E-): *Returns the greatest element in this set less than **or equal** to the given element*, and similar for [`ceiling()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#ceiling-E-), so `C2` would be returned from both calls.